# How to loop through two lists at the same time - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to loop through two lists at the same time

For example

```
List A = ['Chapter 1','Chapter 2','Chapter 3'];
List B = ['Paragraph 1','Paragraph 2','Paragraph 3'];

for(var chapter in A)  // This would itreate through only first list (A), How can I iterate through both list
children: [
     Text(chapter);   
     Text(paragraph);
]
```

I need to iterate through both lists at the same time in "for" loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
  List A = ['Chapter 1','Chapter 2','Chapter 3'];
  List B = ['Paragraph 1','Paragraph 2','Paragraph 3'];
  for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
      print ("${A[i]}");
      print ("${B[i]}");
  }
```

Let me know if this does not help.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
final c = zip([a, b]).map((item) => Foo(item[0], item[1])).toList();
```

Comment: `zip` is not part of the Dart SDK, so you should specify where to get it from.

Comment: package:collection, class IterableZip.

Answer (score 0):

I went along with Randal Schwartz's note about [IterableZip](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableZip-class.html). Note that I was not able to find any `zip` mentioned by Gbenga, and also note that `package:collection/iterable_zip.dart` is deprecated, you'd need to import simply the `collection.dart`, like so:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

final A = ['Chapter 1','Chapter 2','Chapter 3'];
final B = ['Paragraph 1','Paragraph 2','Paragraph 3'];
for (final pairs in IterableZip([A, B])) {
    print(pairs[0]);
    print(pairs[1]);
}
```

Some more notes:

- `final A` and `final B` variables will be typed `List<String>` lists, I disadvise dynamic `List A`.
- I have not specified template type for `IterableZip`, but in some cases (in a complex case where I used it) you may need to explicitly type it like `IterableZip<String>`, so in the loop you can more conveniently access the members. In this simple case the compiler/interpreter can infer the type easily.
- Some other answers in other StackOverflow issues mention quiver, but unless you need it for some other features you don't have to add another extra package dependency to your project. The standard collection package has this `IterableZip`